# Kotlin create new object using another object as the default constructor params

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
data class Person(val age: Int, val name: String)
```

Is there a simple way to create a new `Person` object using another object as a template to fill in the required constructor params?

```kotlin
// Example of what I'd like to be able to do

val person1 = Person(age = 35, name = "Cory")

val person2 = Person(person1, name = "Jeff")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `copy()` method, available in data classes, and override parameters you want to change:

```
val person1 = Person(age = 35, name = "Cory")
val person2 = person1.copy(name = "Jeff")
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying

Answer (score 2):

Every data class in Kotlin has a copy function:

```kotlin
val person2 = person1.copy(name = "Jeff") // but its age is still 35 (from Cory)
```

All parameters are optional in the copy function, so you can overwrite / change the ones you like.

> Note that the copy() call performs a shallow copy

See: [Data Class Copying](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying)